# Again .NET TcpClient and Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient

I've read much on TcpClient and multithreading at stackoverflow but think I didn't find a clear answer to this.

I have an application with 3 identical threads.
(calling the same method on each thread object)

Every thread creates his own (local) TcpClient instance and opens a tcp connection to his server (different IP addresses).

The threads are supposed to do the same things only on a different server.
The 3 server machines are running identical server software.

Now the 3 threads start a server request 'at the same time'.

Are the TcpClient objects totally isolated on each thread ?
Or may it be that the underlying streams are unwillingly shared ?

I got the feeling that sometimes a thread gets data that's not from 'his' server.
For examlpe all threads are polling for a 'ready' flag. 
Only Server 1 is ready and sets the flag, but thread 1 AND thread 2 see the flag set.

There's a good chance that I'm doing things wrong.
But it would help to surely know that communication on the TcpClient objects in this way is safe.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions,
Ralf

PS: And yes, I am currently reading books and documentation on multithreading in C# 8-))

Comment: What have you tried exactly? I don't really see a question, I see a "is this true?" question, but unless you give us more information to work with, we can't answer that type of question.  In addition to not understand the question there are a great deal of grammar and spelling mistakes, this question needs some work, work that needs to be done by the author itself when the additional information is posted.

Comment: @all: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

If the `TcpClient` instances are separate, then they won't be sharing any state - you can use as many `TcpClient` instances as you need. If data is leeching between threads, I can only assume that it is in your own code. A common cause of confusion here is captured variables (anything from a lambda / anon-method), which prior to C# 5 can be shared in ways that the casual reviewer might not anticipate. Without more info we can't say more, but no: they should not interfere with each-other.

Comment: +1 Yes - I can't see any reson for a flag value read from one server to 'bleed' into that from another, (assuming no silly globals/statics).

Comment: May there be a port problem as Mcolli guessed?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the port to which a server send the response back. Afaik the source port is determinatet automaticily depending on the programm which sends a request to a server. Perhaps the port determination does not differ between each threat, so the three simultaneous running threats recive an answer on the same port... but thats only my guess I am not very into TCP-stuff